# В чём отличие между less и sass?

Tags: less, вёрстка, sass, css

Служат для одной и той же цели, имеют похожие методы, а в сущности различаются только синтаксисом и расширением? По мне все же sass поудобнее(покороче) будет, как считаете?

Comment: Давайте, может, переименуем вопрос вo "В чём отличие между less и sass"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

отличий куча во первых sass на ruby, less на js синтаксис оч сильно отличается посмотри на примеры:

- http://lesscss.org/
- http://sass-lang.com/

ну а про расширение я бы сказал в последнюю очередь. Чтобы окончательно все расставить по местам читай вот что: [SASS против LESS](http://habrahabr.ru/post/144309/)

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле less попроще, удобнее и очень легко понять суть препроцессоров на нем. SASS имеет разные плюшки, более строгий. Лично я для себя использую LESS, в первую очередь из-за простоты и скорости сборки. К SASS есть прикольная надстройка Compass. По-моему если уж SASS, то тогда с Compass. Но компилится он жутко долго. У меня LESS версия бутстрапа - 1-2 секунды против 10-15 SASS. Чувтсвуется разница, не так-ли?

Ну и да, смотрите статью на хабре в ответе Павла.